Problem Gave up waiting for root file systemroot file system device in ubuntu 24.04 after trying to do Dual boot with windows
I tried to do the dual-boot (windows after Ubuntu) but something went wrong, after dividing the disk into two partitions of the main system and another empty one, all this using a live USB, after restarting the computer and trying to connect to the main Ubuntu system (24.04), I have this error, all image of the disk (Gparted, and Terminal) I took it using a live USB.
Please help me solve this problem, here are all the error images that might help:
The output of sudo blkid in a terminal of the live USB:

The disk partition from Gparted:

The error when turning on the computer:

Same error after writing exit:

NOTE:
I think I have a backup, when I accessed Gparted from the live USB, it said:

The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK


